# JS: .apply(null, arguments) -- Why is my function called once, whilst console.log called many times?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through Chapter 5 of the excellent [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html).

I'm trying to understand the .apply function.

> JavaScript functions have an apply method. You pass it an array (or array-like object) of arguments, and it will call the function with those arguments.

The example given is:

```
function transparentWrapping(f) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}
```

Trying it out for myself, I wrote this:

```
function doIt(f) {
    return function(arg) { return f.apply(null, arguments) };
}

doIt(console.log)("Hello there!","Hi!","Hello!!", "Testing");
```

The output is:

```
Hello there! Hi! Hello!! Testing
```

However, if I swap console.log for my own function:

```
function logIt(arg) {
    console.log(arg+"\r");
}

doIt(logIt)("Hello there!","Hi!","Hello!!", "Testing");
```

...its seems that the logIt() function is only called for the first argument. The output is:

```
Hello there!
```

Why is console.log called for each argument but logIt only for the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` **isn't** called for each argument. It is just a function that does something with each of the arguments it is passed. It only gets invoked once.

```
console.log("Hello there!","Hi!","Hello!!", "Testing");
```

If it was invoked multiple times:

```
console.log("Hello there!");
console.log("Hi!");
console.log("Hello!!");
console.log("Testing");
```

… then the output would put each string on a separate line.

`logIt`, on the other hand, only does anything with the *first* argument you pass it.

```
logIt("Hello there!","Hi!","Hello!!", "Testing");
```